# how load external configuration class in spring boot

Tags: spring-boot

I have a spring boot application
The structure of my application is:

```
src
    main
        java
            org
                Application.java
                service
                        --another classes are here
```

Application.java

```
package org.baharan;
    import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
    import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

    @SpringBootApplication
    public class Application {

        public static void main(String[] args) throws Throwable {
            SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
        }
    }
```

Another confirguration class files sush as oracle config and security config are in another application(is named core) is added in my pom.xml

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.baharan.amad</groupId>
            <artifactId>core</artifactId>
            <version>1.0-releases</version>
            <type>war</type>
        </dependency>
```

When i build my application, all of classes and properties files of core application are added in my target by overlay maven
When i excute Application.java,spring boot couldn't find any config class isn't in my application but they are in core(after build all of them is added in my target) 
In other word how spring boot load configuration classes which dont exist in current application.
please help me.

Comment: http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html

Answer (score -1):

If they're spring configs you can still use `@ComponentScan` to load in other bean configs e.g.

`@ComponentScan("classpath*:com.myorg.conf")`

and

`@ComponentScan("classpath*:conf/appCtx.xml")`

Comment: @ComponentScan work when com.myorg.conf package must be in your application<br />when com.myorg.conf package is in jar file in web-inf/lib,@ComponentScan does not work